# Fruit Fly in my condo

Tags: pest-control, pest

Every weekend we leave the condo to go back to our main house in the province. Every time we come back in the condo after less than 2 days, there will always be a LOT of DEAD flies (maybe fruit flies cause they are small) near the window and the floors of my room near the aircon as well. It's been like this for the past months and I wonder why they are not a lot when we are here in the condo but reproduce a lot and die immediately when we are not here. Plus please help me get rid of them the easiest way

Comment: Do you remove and dispose of all food waste/garbage from the condo when leaving for the weekend?

Comment: Hello! Yes we throw our trash everyday and made sure no trash is left before leaving the condo

Comment: Do you have houseplants? They'll breed in the potting compost/soil.

Comment: Explain "near the Aircon" more.  Window, split or central air?  Near the registers? Intake?  Blower?

Comment: Once I was finding small dead bugs near windows it turned out they were coming from the pantry.  Do you keep any flour, meal, cereal, rice etc in the home?  If so check them.  If that turns out to be the problem, don't store them more than a year and keep them in hard plastic containers, not just in the bags they come in.  The bugs can poke through soft plastic.

Answer (score 1):

Likely there is standing water from condensation inside the air conditioner. While the AC is on, the insects cannot use the constantly-moving water, but when it's off for a while, it provides a breeding ground.

1. Make sure all drain holes in the AC are unplugged.
2. Consider using a biocide, such as [these examples](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=air%20conditioner%20biocide%20tablets). Caution: some biocides might be unsafe.
3. You might try [DIY fruit fly traps](https://www.thespruce.com/get-rid-of-fruit-flies-1388144), placed near where the flies wer found.

BTW, as [G. Marx stated](https://www.bentonparkprints.com/listing/155182324/time-flies-like-an-arrow-fruit-flies), "Time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a banana."

Comment: Adhesive traps -- flypaper, or the newer approaches which mount to the window -- do work. So do the vinegar/cider traps. But most important is not leaving scraps of food and/or garbage exposed for them to feed/breed on.

Comment: thank you for this but I wonder why they get to die that quick like in less than a day

Comment: Maybe they don't have any food, while you are away.

Comment: They are already dead, he can't kill them again.